# Motherboard doesn't recognize my second GPU

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, gpu, pci-express

I just bought a GTX 750 Ti to accompany my GTX 1070, hoping to use it to make Blender go faster (and maybe for hackintoshy purposes), but my plans have been thwarted by Windows (or rather, the motherboard) not recognizing the 750Ti.
The motherboard is an Asus Z170-Deluxe and I'm using an i7-6700K.
The card in question is a Palit GTX 750 Ti StormX Dual.

Have a photo of the motherboard:
[image: Photo of an Asus Z170-Deluxe with the PCIe slots highlighted in green]
The 1070 is plugged into the right highlighted PCIe slot and it's receiving power from the PC's PSU, while the 750 Ti is plugged into the left highlighted PCIe slot. It only requires 60W to run, so it's not receiving any external power.
The 750 Ti's fans are spinning as I write this, so that seems to be working.

I tried going into the UEFI BIOS (*yes, I know*) to check whether I missed some important settings, but even it doesn't recognize the GPU:
[image: Photo of the UEFI BIOS GPU listing, showing only the GTX 1070]

What's going on here?

Apologies if this exact question has been asked before, but I couldn't find any question dealing with the problem I have right now.

Comment: Ummmm reseat it maybe? I also don't know how well it will do with improving Blender. From the sounds of it, you want an SLI configuration but you're not doing SLI. I've heard of some people doing your type of setup and using just one card as a PhysX processor. Multiple GPU's really isn't my expertise so hopefully someone else has better advice than I do. Also, do you have two monitors or just one?

Comment: Are you sure the 750 even works?  If you remove your 1070 and plug the 750 into its slot, does the system boot and does the UEFI show the card inserted?

Comment: I'll try reseating it. I'm not going for an SLI setup here; as far as I know, it's not even possible with a 1070 and a 750. I'm getting myself a second monitor after christmas, but I'll probably connect that one to the 1070 as well.

Comment: I think I'm slightly confused on the performance benefit you're trying to achieve. Like I stated earlier, you could use the 750 Ti as a PhysX processor, but I don't quite understand what you're trying to improve in Blender?

Comment: A quick search indicates that Cycles, Blender's raytracing renderer, would benefit from a second GPU: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/how-will-two-gpus-improve-cycles-performance Also, I never mentioned PhysX.

Comment: Also, Nvidia's drivers for macOS don't support the Pascal architecture yet, so I got this older card to be able to use macOS.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just accidentally solved my problem.

I guess the card wasn't seated properly, because after swapping PCIe slots a couple of times and reinstalling the graphics drivers from scratch, both cards are working.

[image: yay!]

I'll leave it at that and hope that I'll never have to mess around in my computer's insides again.

Comment: Accept your own answer since this is what solved the question you asked. Just check the checkbox to the upper left of your answer and turn it green!!